# Custom java.sql.Driver Implementation Connection Handling

Tags: java, jdbc

Currently, I load the below custom driver (TestDriver.java), get a connection, create a Statement, execute a query, gets the results and close the connection.  I open and close a connection for each query.  Is this common practice or is there an standard way to share the open connections?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class.forName("com.sql.TestDriver");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:test://8888/connectme", props);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table");
        //loop through rs and pull out needed data
        conn.close();  
    }


    public class TestDriver implements java.sql.Driver{
        private final TestSchema schema;
        private Properties props = null;
        static {
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new TestDriver());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        protected TestDriver() throws SQLException {
            schema = TestSchemaFactory.getInstance().getDbSchemaFromFile(SCHEMA_FILE);
            //loads in and parses a file containing tables, columns used for business logic
        }
        public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) 
                throws SQLException {
           TestSqlConnection conn=null;
           //connect logic here
           return conn; //will return an instance of TestSqlConnection
        }

    @Override
    public boolean jdbcCompliant() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's more common to use a database connection pool.  This will allow connections to be reused without the overhead or closing/re-opening.  Here's a link to DBCP which is one implementation of a database connection pool: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

Answer (score 1):

1. Ideally you should write a separate factory class (can be static)
   say ConnectionFactory which returns a connection object.
2. Also I see that you are not using try/catch/finally block while creating
   connection.I strongly suggest to close the connection in finally
   clause otherwise you program may suffer from connection leak if any
   exception is raised and causes abrupt behavior.
3. Ideally you should close the connection after your operation is complete in finally
   clause.In web based application if you are using connections pool
   then closing connection will return the connection back to pool and
   will be available for use.

Comment: great comments.  My java main was just an example.  All of your comments are valid.